# live search with MySQL database using Json and display result in listview android

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

i am working of live search with MySQL, JSON. its working fine with local array values. but not working with MySQL. my concern is when user start typing it has to search from data base and show it in listview. bellow is my Adapter for search

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import zesteve.com.myapplication.R;
import zesteve.com.myapplication.Search;
import zesteve.com.myapplication.VendProfileActivity;

/**
 * Created by Ravi Shankar on 6/22/2017.
 */

public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Search> vendersearchlist = null;
    private ArrayList<Search> arraylist;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context,
                           List<Search> vendersearchlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.vendersearchlist = vendersearchlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Search>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(vendersearchlist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView vname;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vendersearchlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Search getItem(int position) {
        return vendersearchlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_item_list, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            //holder.id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            holder.vname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        //holder.rank.setText(Search.get(position).getRank());
        holder.vname.setText(vendersearchlist.get(position).getVname());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, VendProfileActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("Vend_Id",
                        (vendersearchlist.get(position).getId()));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("Vend_Name",
                        (vendersearchlist.get(position).getVname()));
                // Pass all data population

                // Start SingleItemView Class
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        vendersearchlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            vendersearchlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Search sl : arraylist) {
                if (sl.getVname().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    vendersearchlist.add(sl);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**AND POJO**

```
public class Search {
    private int id;
    private String vname;

    public Search(int id, String vname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.vname = vname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getVname() {
        return this.vname;
    }

}
```

And my `SearchActivity.java`

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Response;
import zesteve.com.myapplication.adapter.SearchAdapter;
import zesteve.com.myapplication.adapter.VenderAdapter;

public class Search_vender extends AppCompatActivity {

    String  catname,city;
    int catid;

    private EditText Vendname;
    private Session session;
    ListView listview;
    SearchAdapter adapter;
    int[] id;
    String[] vname;
    ArrayList<Search> vendersearchlist = new ArrayList<Search>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_vender);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        session = new Session(Search_vender.this);

        catid = getIntent().getIntExtra("CatId",00);
        catname= getIntent().getStringExtra("CatName");
        city = session.getUserLocation().get(session.KEY_UCITY);


        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Vendname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchitem);
        Vendname.setHint("Search "+catname+" in "+city);


        //fetch data from server in json
        String vsearch = Vendname.getText().toString();
        prepareVender(vsearch);


        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, vendersearchlist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml

        Vendname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = Vendname.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareVender(String sText){

        AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://api.zesteve.com/vend_list.php?city="+city+"&catid="+catid+"&name="+strings[0])
                        .build();
                try{
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject object= array.getJSONObject(i);

                        Search vender = new Search(object.getInt("id"),

                                object.getString("name"));

                        vendersearchlist.add(vender);
                    }

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("End of Catagory");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        task.execute(sText);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please comment if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

if Somebody looking for same Solution. bellow is my code

```
public class Search_vender extends AppCompatActivity {

    String  catname,city;
    int catid;

    SearchView Vendname;
    private Session session;
    ListView listview;
    SearchAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Search> vendersearchlist = new ArrayList<Search>();
    ArrayList<Search> filteredSearchResults = new ArrayList<Search>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_vender);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        session = new Session(Search_vender.this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search_vender.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        catid = getIntent().getIntExtra("CatId",00);
        catname= getIntent().getStringExtra("CatName");
        city = session.getUserLocation().get(session.KEY_UCITY);

        //Toast.makeText(Search_vender.this,catid + city,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Vendname = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchitem);
        Vendname.setQueryHint("Search "+catname+" in "+city);




        Vendname.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Toast.makeText(Search_vender.this, String.valueOf(hasFocus),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Vendname.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if(newText.length() > 2){

                    listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    GetDataVender gv = (GetDataVender) new GetDataVender().execute(newText);
                }else{

                    listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void filterSearchArray(String newText){
        String pName;

        filteredSearchResults.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < vendersearchlist.size(); i++)
        {
            pName = vendersearchlist.get(i).getVname().toLowerCase();
            if ( pName.contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
            {
                filteredSearchResults.add(vendersearchlist.get(i));
            }
        }
    }


    class GetDataVender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        String textsearch;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Please Wait...");
            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://api.zesteve.com/autosearch.php?city="+city+"&catid="+catid+"&name="+strings[0])
                    .build();
            this.textsearch = strings[0];
            try {

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject object =array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Search catagory = new Search(object.getInt("id"),
                            object.getString("name"));

                    vendersearchlist.add(catagory);
                }

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("End of Catagory");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result != null && result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
                Toast.makeText(Search_vender.this, "Unable to connect to server,please try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }else{

                filterSearchArray(textsearch);
                listview.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(Search_vender.this,filteredSearchResults));
                hideDialog();
            }

            //hideDialog();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

it works when user stat search from second character.